# Once established, are sockets on localhost secure?

Tags: server, tcp

Once a TCP socket has been established on `localhost`, and a connection made using `accept`, is it possible for a non-privileged user to intercept or modify bytes sent over this connection, or can this connection be guaranteed secure?

Operating systems in question are Windows and any modern variation on Unix.  Windows is the most important as I can use Unix domain sockets on other platforms.

I will use authentication (16 byte random key stored in a file) to ensure that malicious connections are immediately dropped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are safe regarding the described threat since in any case intercepting and altering network traffic at a low-level always requires the user to have elevated privileges on the local machine. An unprivileged end-user being unable intercept or tamper with them, **you can therefore consider local connections as secure**.

However, your question raises an interesting point I would-like to deepen a bit, especially if we lax a bit the "unprivileged end-user" perspective. Indeed, you mention Windows and Unix in your question, but the situation is quite different for these.

On Windows (and a few Unixes, namely Solaris and HP-UX), for optimization purposes (I guess) loopback communications do not go through a full IP stack. Therefore, under normal circumstances it is not possible to intercept, and even more so to alter local communication.

I say "*under normal circumstances*" because there is still the possibility to force the Windows host to route its local traffic through a nearby router, effectively forcing the data to travel through the full host's IP stack. This can be used to investigate a communication which could not be intercepted otherwise, however it would require to be administrator of the local machine to enforce such routing and the operation will not be discreet at all (route table with a new entry, the switch/router which will see unusual traffic, the application which will suddenly become very slow, etc.).

Alternatively, there is still the possibility to access raw socket communication and there are also a few commercial software offering IP sniffing on local interfaces. I'm not sure whether such solution can allow the communication to be altered and it seems it would require far more work anyway. You can find more information on the subject on the [Wireshark website](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

At the opposite, most Unix and Unix-like systems implement the loopback as any other network device, allowing to intercept the communication occurring on it as you would do with any other network interface, and thus allowing at least theorically the communication to be altered. I remind though that this would still require the potential attacker to have already acquired enough privileges on the host, at such point chances are that there are easier ways to exploit your application.